# Form with checkbox to update sql table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to update a MySQL table from an html form.

This is a piece of the form:

```
<div id="caricoModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form method="post" id="employeeForm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Edit User</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tipoOp" class="control-label">Operazione:</label>
                        <select id="tipo" name="tipo" class="form-control">
                            <option value="carico">Carico</option>
                            <option value="scarico">Scarico</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Record list -->
                    <table border='0' style='border-collapse: collapse;' >
                        <tr style='background: whitesmoke;'>
                            <!-- Check/Uncheck All-->
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>Stato</th>
                        </tr>

    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users where stato='0'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $stato = $row['stato'];
    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- Checkbox -->
                            <td><input type='checkbox' name='update[]' value='<?= $id ?>' ></td>
                        
                            <td><?= $id ?></td>

                            <td><input type='number' name='stato_<?= $id ?>' value='<?= $stato ?>' ></td>

                        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
            </table>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">                            
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Data Formulario</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datafr" name="datafr" placeholder="Data Formulario" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" required>          
    </div>
```

When i submit the dialog form, i call a method for add a new row in my table; i would to make a query based on the checkbox choices.

This is the method for add a new row:

```
public function addCarico(){
            
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$this->empTable." 
                (data_fr, data_trasporto, codice_eer, stato_fisico, 
                classi_pericolo, formulario, produttore, trasportatore, 
                destinatario, quantità, note, carico, stato_carico) 
            VALUES ('".$_POST["datafr"]."', '".$_POST["datatr"]."', 
                    '".$_POST["eer"]."', '".$_POST["statof"]."', 
                    '".$_POST["pericolo"]."', '".$_POST["fr"]."', 
                    '".$_POST["prod"]."', '".$_POST["trasp"]."', 
                    '".$_POST["dest"]."', '".$_POST["qta"]."', 
                    '".$_POST["note"]."', '1', '0')";
    $isUpdated = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $insertQuery);  
    print_r($_POST['update']);
}
```

I tried to add this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    foreach($_POST['update'] as $updateid){

        $stato = $_POST['stato_'.$updateid];

        if($stato !=''){
            $updateUser = "UPDATE users SET 
                stato='1' 
            WHERE id=".$updateid;
            mysqli_query($con,$updateUser);
        }
        
    }
}
```

But i don't understand because the table isnt updated..

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on

Comment: To get errors out of PHP _even in a LIVE environment_ add these 4 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Do you know if the code is getting INTO the `if(isset($_POST['update'])){`

Answer (score 0):

I would check mysql error log and eventually try to enable query log temporarily with SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'. Plus, as @RiggsFolly suggested, enable as much as possible to debug the code and find if some error show up and add an `echo 'what you want'` inside the if isset($_POST).

Comment: The action attribute is assigned by js; at the end of the form there is: ```<div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="hidden" name="empId" id="empId" />
         <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" />
       
```
action is assigned by this code:
```  $('#carico').click(function(){
  $('#caricoModal').modal('show');
  $('#employeeForm')[0].reset();
  $('.modal-title').html("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Carico/Scarico");
  $('#action').val('addEmployee');
  $('#save').val('Add');
 }); 
```

this code assign addEmploye action, that is defined in action1.php

Answer (score -1):

do various things to check the update query.

1. check that you are receiving in the variable $ _POST ['update']
2. Print the query update that you are going to perform
3. Check that the query is correct

If all this is OK, it is possibly the connection to the database that is not working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).